# Python argcomplete, setting in /etc/bash_completion.d/

Tags: python, python-3.x, command-line-arguments, argparse

I am writing a system utility in Python that I am placing directly in `/usr/bin/myScript`.

I want to setup my script with argcomplete globally, where a user doesn't need to run the `eval "$(register-python-argcomplete3 /usr/bin/myScript)"` command. This eval command is successful, but just not global.

I am trying to accomplish this by piping the output to a bash completion file: `register-python-argcomplete3 myScript > /etc/bash_completion.d/myScript`, but this fails to make the autocomplete happen (nothing happens on tabbing the script options in terminal). I have also tried logging out and back in, also rebooting for good measure.

I also have the `# PYTHON_ARGCOMPLETE_OK` directive at the top of my script (under `#!/bin/python3`), but how this works is a little confusing and unintuitive, and not much comes of the `activate-global-python-argcomplete` command seemingly. The `/etc/bash_completion.d/python-argcomplete` script is created, but still no autocomplete for my script.

How can I make sure the autocomplete is available for my script globally?